# Fiddler not capturing traffic. Proxy settings keep getting changed

Tags: fiddler

A few days ago, a yellow banner started to appear in Fiddler reporting that my proxy settings had changed and that if I clicked the yellow banner, I could re-enable Fiddler traffic capture.

Upon clicking, the banner and the error message wouldn't go, and Fiddler had stopped capturing all traffic.

I searched the Web and found how to change the proxy settings back to 127.0.0.1 and port 8888.

However, when I do that, something keeps setting the port number back to 63758.

The version of Fiddler I am using is v2.4.9.9 on a Windows 7 Home Premium PC.

Please see picture attached. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This probably belongs on Superuser rather than StackOverflow.
2. You don't need to "search the web" to change your proxy settings, just click the big yellow bar.
3. You'll need to find what is changing your proxy settings. My guess is that you're infected with Adware like `BrowserSafeguard` or `GeniusBox`. You can either use `netstat -a -o` to find the process listening on the port in question, or you can use SysInternals' Process Monitor to watch the `Proxy Server` registry key and see who is changing it.

Comment: Eric, I tried the instructions given here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-auto-reset-fiddler-when-%27system-proxy-was-changed%27 Nothing shows up after applying the two filters mentioned there. There is also the problem of fiddler not being able to track google's https connections.

Comment: Feel free to remove the filters, take the log capture, and send it to me. But stepping back, are you using VPN or 3rd-party security software?

Comment: I do have 3rd-party software to control installations, rights and also 3rd party anti virus. I did not use vpn while testing fiddler.

Comment: Security software at companies might change the proxy settings and take over. They keep monitoring the settings and will undo fiddler's settings as soon as you click reenable capturing. After the spat of ransomware, more and more companies are using these types of security software rendering Fiddler useless. You can start using network sniffers that do not use proxies. Fiddling (pun unintended) with the security software to make them work with Fiddler might get you into trouble at your company.