# Using a third party Windows Application, Fiddler Classic's proxy changes, "click to reenable" capturing. Are any requests getting by unnoticed?

Tags: proxy, windows-10, fiddler, network-traffic

I recently began using Fiddler to capture requests from a windows application that I believe is sending malevolent requests. This said application actually has a browser extension for both Chrome and Microsoft Edge. However, only on the Windows Application does Fiddler gives me a yellow pop up: "The System proxy was changed, click to reenable Fiddler capture." This happens specifically when the App begins running and the user logs in.

An example is seen on here: [Fiddler not capturing traffic. Proxy settings keep getting changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764968/fiddler-not-capturing-traffic-proxy-settings-keep-getting-changed)

I also notice in my windows machine network proxy settings that the App automatically checks "use a setup script" and provides a link to their proxy script.

On my machine, I clearly still am seeing many requests after clicking the yellow pop up. I also am still seeing many requests called by this App. However, I am worried that there could be an instance where the App is clearly able to send requests that it can hide from Fiddler, and only let Fiddler see the requests it wants it to.

The reason I believe this is that Fiddler is a proxy, and the App is yet another proxy. Fiddler doesn't know that it's intercepting a network's traffic through the App's proxy. So Fiddler wouldn't know if it's not hearing everything, and neither would I.

Is this a realistic fear?

If so, where can I find some more information on what is happening, and how to bypass it?

If not, that's all I need to know.

Comment: If you want to make sure that you capture all traffic use a second machine and capture traffic on network level, e.g. using Wireshark and using Mitmproxy in transparent mode. Make sure that the computer you want to sniff data from can only reach internet through the second PC where you sniff the traffic.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to capture traffic on a remote machine using Fiddler itself, actually. And I made sure the machine I'm sniffing data from was connected to the second through a separate proxy. The traces look the same. This clears it up very well.